# Xcode 4.3.2 - One project on two Macs, errors on one, builds on another

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

UPDATE: QUESTION CLOSED: Fixed myself with a little backtracking. I'm using a framework that requires a source tree variable. (Sparrow). I updated the source tree on my main Mac Mini but not in my MacBook Pro. So, Xcode was searching an old directory due to that mistake.

This may be one of those weird Xcode bugs, so I'm looking for a little advice. I have Xcode 4.3.2 (latest as of this writing Apr 7 2012) installed on two Macs. I have a project saved in Dropbox so I can quickly get at it and work on it from either place. I've done this with several other projects and never experienced this issue.

One one computer, a Mac Mini, the project builds fine. On the other, a 2009 MacBook Pro, I get build errors. For one, even though I'm using -fno-objc-arc on a few of the source files, I am still getting ARC related errors. That is very puzzling to me. No issue when building on the Mac Mini. I'm also getting "file not found" errors pertaining to the .pch file.  The error log is pointing me to a strange path like

```
/var/folders/9l/s_phv6yj0hv6q82_lrdcckb00000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/...Prefix.pch' file not found
```

Here's what I've tried so far

- Deleted Xcode and reinstalled from the MAS
- Deleted the /var/folders directory called out in the logs
- Removed the project build directory
- Performed a Product -> Clean in Xcode
- Restarted Xcode numerous times

Still no dice.  Looks like unless I can nail down this issue, I'll be stuck working from one workstation for this project only.  All other projects work fine when doing this.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Where is the /var/folders located?  In your dropbox directory or is it an external reference?  If it is external, make sure that the path is the same on both of your machines.  This looks to me like an external reference in which the 91 and s_ph... sections are likely to be volatile from machine to machine.

Comment: That path exists on my MacBook Pro, not in Dropbox but in the root directory. I followed it all the way down and there was no .pch file in that directory. I tried dropping a copy in there with no luck.

Comment: In that case I am stumped so I will upvote this question.  The most I can say with any confidence is that the error is almost certainly an erroneous build setting.  You could try creating a new project and copy all your files in if it doesnt require too much time.

Comment: That SharedPrecompiledHeaders directory leads to your prefix file (because it takes so long to compile), or if you code in multiple languages, many prefix files (one for each language).  does the prefix file exist in the first place, and is does your 'precompiled headers cache path' match on both machines?

Comment: I would close Xcode, delete the build folder and relaunch Xcode. I don't think the problem is related to Dropbox.

Comment: Stupid question, but they're both on exactly the same build of Xcode and Mac OS X right? Are you using any custom frameworks which might be stored not in Dropbox but somewhere on your computer?

Comment: I fixed it, stupid mistake on my part. I'm closing the question but I up voted each of your comments. See my update in the original question

Comment: @JustinXXVII Feel free to post & accept your own answer to make this question a better resource in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a Source Tree variable in XCode, and one of the variables was out of date and pointing to the wrong path. One of the source files that was subsequently updated was working on one Mac but throwing errors on the other, which caused the build to fail and the linker to display strange errors.